# JPA @TableGenerator shared between multiple entities - part 2

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1

I have a follow up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741402/jpa-tablegenerator-shared-between-multiple-entities) SO question, since we are a few JPA versions further since 2010 and as stated in the comments under the answer:

> I tried it... it SEEMS to work only because the allocation size is 1. But actually separate generators are created ans work separately. If you choose an allocation size greater than 1, you will see that you will have different id ranges for each entity. (Using Hibernate 3.6 here, maybe it works better with 4.x ?)

I want to use one `@TableGenerator` to generate id's for multiple JPA entities. So, let's assume two entities:

```
@Entity
public class MaritalStatus {
    @Id
    @TableGenerator(
            name = "appSeqStore", 
            table = "APP_SEQ_STORE", 
            pkColumnName = "NAME", 
            pkColumnValue = "ReferenceTables", 
            valueColumnName = "VALUE", 
            initialValue = 0, 
            allocationSize = 11)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "appSeqStore")
    private Long id;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Country {
    @Id
    // Can I reference the same generator here?
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "appSeqStore")
    private Long id;
}
```

Both entities are not related, so there is not `@MappedSuperclass` or something like that, the first stores the marital status and the second one countries. However, I do want them to get id's from the same sequence, so there will never be an overlap in id's of marital status and countries. Both id's also need to be 11-proof.

Questions:

1. If I don't want an `@MappedSuperclass`, can I work with one `@TableGenerator` or do I need to copy the generator in each entity?
2. If the first question is not possible, and I do use an `@MappedSuperclass`, is that a solution to stop the code duplication?

I am using Hibernate JPA 2.1 on WildFly 8.2