# Can use a shared table for all entities when using GenerationType.SEQUENCE?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

We create more than 100 tables in a schema in our application we used GenerationType.IDENTITY but this strategy does not support batching insert so we wanna switch to GenerationType.SEQUENCE.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class DataObject implements Serializable {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "idgen")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
}

@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(initialValue = 1, name = "idgen", sequenceName = "entityaseq")
@Table(name = "entity_a")
public class EntityA extends DataObject { 
}

@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(initialValue = 1, name = "idgen", sequenceName = "entitybseq")
@Table(name = "entity_b")
public class EntityB extends DataObject {
}
```

Reference:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12329?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

But this creates one table sequence for each table entity and this is very over.

Can there be any workaround to make a shared table for all entities?

Answer (score 1):

Shared sequence for all Entities that extend `DataObject`:

First define the sequence in the MappedSuperclass:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class DataObject implements Serializable {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="idgen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="idgen", sequenceName="entity_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
}
```

Then remove any annotations about sequence from your Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_a")
public class EntityA extends DataObject { 
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_b")
public class EntityB extends DataObject {
}
```

This way suppose you save EntityA and gets id `1`, a subsequent save to EntityB will use the same sequence and will get id `2`.

Comment: Thanx @pleft I was mean a single sequence table with next_val for each table id.
For example table A and B and table sequence that has two sequences for each table A and B.
Can we do that?

Comment: Maybe you can use a `@TableGenerator` but it is not recommended as I read. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741402/jpa-tablegenerator-shared-between-multiple-entities and https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-never-use-the-table-identifier-generator-with-jpa-and-hibernate/